# How come the return value of the static, non-local returned pointer is always zero?

Tags: c++, pointers, static, heap-memory, callstack

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointer);
int main()
{
 int chaka;
 int sheppa;
 int *lostlove;
 take(chaka, sheppa, lostlove);
 cout << lostlove;
}
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointer)
{
 pointer = &takevalue;
 return *pointer;
}
```

The above code works fine, but poiner's value is 0. So, I tried doing to non-locally, where the data represented will be from the heap and automatically deleted when the program ends:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static int *pointer = 0;
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointers);
int main()
{
int chaka;
int sheppa;
take(chaka, sheppa, pointer);
cout << pointer;
}
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointers)
{
pointer = &takevalue;
return *pointer;
}
```

However, "pointer's" value is still 0, even after being assigned the address of takevalue. Shouldn't takevalue have an address when the call stack is used? Why is pointer always 0?

Comment: Your code doesn't compiler (`pointers` and `pointer`). You should copy your actual code.  BTW, the answer is that the pointer is passed by value.

Comment: @EdS. Both code samples in the question compile. There is a parameter `pointers`, but that doesn't mean the global variable `pointer` stops existing.

Comment: @EdS. Pointers is the parameter, but the static passed int is pointer. The difference means nothing; both compile for me. A parameter name doesn't require matching of the argument when called.

Comment: @hvd: I didn't even see that declaration, my mistake.

Comment: @AndyHarglesis: That's not what I was referring to.  I was pointing out `pointer` used in `take`, but didn't see that it was declared statically.

Comment: Why do you have parameters `doubleTake` and `pointers` you are not using in example 2?  And why does example 2 work for me http://ideone.com/1Uwrnw

Answer (score 1):

you expect to change the value of pointer from the take's parameter, but it won't happen because int* pointer will be local to your function. You need to make a double pointer (or ref pointer) if you want to change the value of the pointer. example:

```
take(int& value, int** pointer) {
    *pointer = &value;
}
```

this will change the address pointed by your pointer.

Comment: How so would a doubel pointer do that? Wouldn't it still be local to the function on the stack?

Comment: int** will be local (meaning you won't be able to change int** outside the function), but you can change what int** points to (which is pointer value, int*). Try to research more about function parameters and pointer (especially pointer). A pointer is only a 32bits (or 64bits) address which points to a memory address. Those 32bits will be local to your function. That's why a int** will help here.

Comment: But it's static, so what's thhe difference from passing it as an argument and just assigning it right at the spot with the local variable?

Comment: because you declared it at a global scope, outside your main, which means it's accessible everywhere.

Comment: @Syl That doesn't answer my question completely though

Answer (score 0):

Running the last program I get

```
[H:\dev\test]
> a
0x23fe4c
[H:\dev\test]
> _
```

Problem solved.

Comment: What about the first one? Any insight?

Comment: @Andy: what about the first one differs from what you expect? Note that the first program can do *anything*, since it uses and outputs an *indeterminate* (un-initialized) pointer value, which is **Undefined Behavior**. UB includes the program causing red nasal daemons to appear.

Answer (score 0):

In this function declaration

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointer);
```

each parameter if it is not a reference is a local variable of the function. So any changes made with such a parameter in the function will be discarded after exiting the function and will not influence on the original argument.

You should declare the first parameter as a reference the same way as the first two parameters

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int * &pointer);
```

As for the second function definition

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointers)
{
pointer = &takevalue;
return *pointer;
}
```

then its third parameter is simply not used. So you could rewrite the function as

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake)
{
pointer = &takevalue;
return *pointer;
}
```

Though the second parameter also is not used.:)

So the function can be even simpler

```
int take(int &takevalue)
{
pointer = &takevalue;
return *pointer;
}
```

Comment: So what's the difference with using it statically from the heap memory allocated outside all functions and passing it also being static?

Comment: @Andy Harglesis The same way as with other references. That is it is a reference to the original argument so any changes will be done with the original argument. That is if you will change the value of the pointer in fact you will change the original pointer.

Comment: Look up again, I revised.

Comment: So what's the difference with using it statically from the heap memory allocated outside all functions and passing it also being static? Essentially, if I can use it without having to pass it as an argument (since it's global), what would be the difference in passing it this way rather than just assigning it?

Comment: @Andy Harglesis And what did you revise? As I already wrote the third parameter in the second function definition is not used. In the body of the function you use directly the global pointer.

Comment: You are not answering my sub-question though.

Comment: @Andy Harglesis See one more my post. I already wrote that the third parameter is not used. The global pointer is used directly in the body of the function.

Comment: But how does that explain the difference between the behavior of the argument of the global pointer with taken value of a local value, then passed back to the caller?

Comment: @Andy Harglesis As far as I see your global variable is not passed as argument. It is used directly in the body of the function. In the first case you pass the local variabloe as an argument to the function. So the function uses a copy of this variable. Any changes of the copy do not influence on the original local variable.

Comment: So that's why the value is 0 when I output the value after returning from the function? Because the passed value is not kept, only used for that subroutine?

Comment: @Andy Harglesis Yoe, if an object is passed by value to a function then its copy is created as the value of the parameter.

Comment: So when the subroutine ends, or better yet when the subroutine starts, the value is always 0; it's just changed to whatever until the stack is cleared? Like in my example, the pointer is 0, but is assigned the value of the passed reference. However, it's outputted when the function ends, showing no value.

Comment: Changes of a copy of an object do not influence the object itself. The function gets a copy of an object passed to the function by value.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. So the original pointer's value is unchanged; only in the function's scope does it change. This is true only until stack popping, right

Answer (score 0):

When you think about what a pointer actually is - an integer whose value is a memory address - things will start getting clearer for you.

So let's look at your original declaration:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointer);
```

This can be thought of like this:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int address);
```

So when you declare this:

```
int *lostlove;
```

You are really declaring something like this:

```
int address_of_an_int;
```

And thus, when you call this:

```
take(chaka, sheppa, lostlove);
```

You are passing the value of `lostlove` **by value** to `take()`.

Now, let's look at what `take()` does:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int *pointer)
{
    pointer = &takevalue;
    return *pointer;
}
```

Thought differently, it is actually doing this:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int address)
{
    address = (int) &takevalue;
    return value_that_is_located_at_address;
}
```

So, as you can see, the last parameter is being passed **by value**, so you are modifying a local variable that only exists within the function.  Since the parameter is not passed **by reference** (like the other parameters are) or **by pointer**, the caller's variable (`lostlove`) cannot be modified with a new value.  That is why you do not see it change.

So, with that in mind, to make your original code work the way you are expecting, you need to do this instead:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int* &pointer);

int main()
{
    int chaka;
    int sheppa;
    int *lostlove;
    take(chaka, sheppa, lostlove);
    cout << lostlove;
}

int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int* &pointer)
{
    pointer = &takevalue;
    return *pointer;
}
```

Or this:

```
int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int **pointer);

int main()
{
    int chaka;
    int sheppa;
    int *lostlove;
    take(chaka, sheppa, &lostlove);
    cout << lostlove;
}

int take(int &takevalue, int &doubletake, int **pointer)
{
    *pointer = &takevalue;
    return **pointer;
}
```